# From Aerodynamic view, what is the advantage/disadvantage of the Akagi Kaman K-Max Helicopter?

Tags: aerodynamics, helicopter

[image: Akagi Kaman K-Max Helicopter]

[Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YgopA7jA6Dg) is a video showing the helicopter, the rotors are perfectly synchronized.

As there are not many such design helicopter, then my question are, is any aerodynamic weakness? What is its advantage/disadvantage of that helicopter?

Answer (score 1):

It's a twin rotor design, counter-rotating: no resulting torque on the airframe and no tail rotor needing to be powered. The twin rotors do not share a common shaft, with all of the [extremely complicated control mechanisms that these require.](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/43261/21091)

From J. Gordon Leishman, Principles of Helicopter Aerodynamics, section 2.15:

> The design advantage of a twin rotor is that all power can be devoted to providing useful vertical lift and performance. However, the two rotors and their wakes interact with one another, producing a somewhat more complicated flow field than is found with a single rotor, and this interacting flow incurs a loss of net rotor system aerodynamic efficiency.

Comment: I believe they are very different between V-22 Ofsprey, Akagi Kaman K-Max, but probably a bit **similar too Chinook Helicopter** (also built by Boeing). What my concern/question here is due to the overlapping blades, which aerodynamically will disturb the wind. V-22's blades are not overlapped at all.

Comment: Indeed, because there is a wing in between the V22 main rotors, creating a much wider aircraft. If the V22 could not tilt its rotors forward, the design would not make much sense.